# using p:fileUpload primefaces 3.5

Tags: jquery-ui, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.5 and i have problem the p:fileUpload compoment.

### browser problem

fileupload.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileupload' of undefined

web page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <ui:composition template="/templates/#{sessionScope['template']}">
        <ui:define name="headerpage">
            <h1>
                Questionnaires
                <small> Consulter Questionnaires</small>
            </h1>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body">
            <p:fileUpload id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{catalogueController.saveImageProduitUpload}" 
                          mode="advanced"
                          sizeLimit="10000000" 
                          multiple="true"
                          allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>
```

Comment: please provide more details on your question like add a snippet of your web page and backing bean. i may help identify your "browser problem"

Comment: ok. can you post also your saveImageProduitUpload method? just to check, have you also included in your web.xml the needed configuration for <filter> and <filter-mapping>?

Comment: yes the filter and filter-mapping exist

Comment: is your p:fileUpload enclosed inside a form? Also, there's a note in the primefaces user guide: "Multiple advanced uploaders in same form is not supported at the moment"

Comment: so i'm dowing like this :  <h:form> <p:fileUpload id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{catalogueController.saveImageProduitUpload}" 
                          mode="advanced"
                          sizeLimit="10000000" 
                          multiple="true"
                          allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/> </h:form>

Comment: can you try adding this attribute to your h:form: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: i think it caused by the jquery lib

Comment: so it seems. when I try to google your error it seems that it is not primefaces related. if you can, try and upgrade to the latest primefaces and see if your problem will be solved